# Please tell me why I am constantly getting a settings sync fail error message when I open VS code

Tags: visual-studio, savechanges

I made the mistake of following a youtube video to improve setup of VS code, after making the adjustments I always get the settings sync error message. I click on show error file, and highlights the editor.fontSize line. I cannot see anything wrong with it personally:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt2",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable",
  "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "michelemelluso.code-beautifier"
  },
  "sync.gist": "7aea226d700927d0abdecbd3c2260369",
  "sync.autoDownload": true,
  "sync.quietSync": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.watchOnLaunch": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/css/style.css"
    },
  ]
}

"editor.fontSize": 14,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons"
```

I have tried uninstalling many many times and all my settings get restored and never go back to default. I have tried advice here as to making some changes from other peoples similar problems, but nothing seems to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, this pops up any time I try to make a settings change also.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete this section

```
 "sync.gist": "7aea226d700927d0abdecbd3c2260369",
  "sync.autoDownload": true,
  "sync.quietSync": true,
```